# JQuery async .each returns empty promises

Tags: jquery, arrays, typescript, object, empty-list

**Problem**

Hi friends,

I am having the problem that the object `promises` is returning me as empty `[]`. While the `console.log` I have documented shows me the data.

If there is a way to solve the problem, I will appreciate it.

```js
const getALLMovies = async(page: number = 1): Promise<IMovies[]> =>{
  const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}peliculas/${page}`);
  const body = await res.data;
  const $ = load(body);
  const promises: IMovies[] = [];  

$('body div div div div div div div div div div div div#default-tab-1 div.Posters a').each(async(index , element) =>{
    const $element = $(element);
    const id = $element.attr('href').replace(BASE_URL , '').trim();
    const title = $element.find('div.listing-content p').text().trim();
    const poster = $element.find('img').attr('src');
    const extra = await contentHandler(id);
    promises.push({
      //id: id || null,
      title: title || null,
      poster: poster || null,
      year:   extra[0].year || null,
      genres: extra[0].genres || null,
      rating: extra[0].rating || null,
      synopsis: extra[0].synopsis || null,
      authors:  extra[0].authors || null,
      director: extra[0].director || null,
      writers:  extra[0].writers || null,
      country:  extra[0].country || null,
      releaseDate: extra[0].releaseDate || null,
    })
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(promises , null , 2)) --> The data is shown here.

  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
};

getALLMovies()
  .then(res =>{
    console.log(res.map(x => x)) --> empty object
  })
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] as described in [ask]; what you're describing doesn't sound possible given the code above, but of course I can't test it myself so ‍♂️.  Good luck!

Comment: I have update my answer to include an example that achieves your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is a race condition.  Your `.each` handler schedules some asynchronous code, namely it has to await the results of `contentHandler`.  As such, when `getALLMovies` is called `promises` is still an empty array, and that array won't be fully populated until all calls to `contentHandler` complete.  I.e. for each element, the result of `contentHandler` is queued up (4 times in the example below).

```js
var promises = [];

function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function go() {
  $("div").each(async() => {
    await timeout(1500);
    console.log("now");
    promises.push("example");
  })
  console.log(promises);
}

go();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

This is how I would alter your code to achieve your desired result:

```js
var promises = [];

function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function go() {
  console.log("go");

  promises = $("div").map(async () => {
    await timeout(1500);
    console.log ("now");
    return "value"; 
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
}

go().then(() => console.log(promises.length));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Also a side note... `body div div div div div div div div div div div div` in your selector is likely irrelevant due to the inclusion of `#default-tab-1` which is a higher order or specificity.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, @Zze, but `async` doesn't move the execution to a new thread.  The handler is added to the message queue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: It's also using the Explicit Promise Construction Anti-Pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23803744/3977276  Create that "new Promise" is not necessary.

Comment: @avejidah Yes, I will update my answer in regards to your first comment. The second comment is not applicable to this example as `go()` is not awaiting the result of internal promises firing, and is in fact in line with the suggested / accepted answer. Please feel free to copy this answer to your own and post if you feel I am incorrect. You would be correct if all it was doing was returning `timeout`, but the OP will be doing other logic in this section.

Comment: I think the second is applicable.  `promises = $("div").map(async () => { await timeout(1500); return "value"; })` avoids the explicit promise construction and results in the same resolution.

Comment: @avejidah ahhhh I see what you are saying, ok. Updated - thanks.

Comment: Hah!  Well that's close, but not quite.  Now `resolve` won't be defined.  Just return "value" and it will be wrapped in a Promise instance automatically.  (E.g. `[].map(async () => {return "value"})`)

Comment: The reason I pointed this out is that by using the aforementioned anti-pattern, failures in the inner asynchronous method (`timeout` in your example) are not propagated.  E.g. the code that calls `go()` cannot `.catch` errors that happen in `timeout.`

Comment: @avejidah Thanks, this has been interesting, I did not know that it implicitly wraps it. Also that is interesting with the error propagation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Zze,

With your example I have managed to show all the data.

**SOLUTION**

```js
const getALLMovies = async(page: number = 1) =>{
  const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}peliculas/${page}`);
  const body = await res.data;
  const $ = load(body);
  const promises: IMovies[] = [];  

  //const actual = page;
  //const lastPage = parseInt($('body div.app div.layout ul.pagination li').eq(4).find('a').attr('href').match(/\d/g).join("") , 10);
  //const pagination = {
  //  actual: actual,
  //  last: lastPage
  //}

  const promise = $('body div#default-tab-1 div.Posters a').map((index , element) => new Promise(async(resolve) =>{
    const $element = $(element);
    const id = $element.attr('href').replace(BASE_URL, '').trim();
    const title = $element.find('div.listing-content p').text().trim();
    const poster = $element.find('img').attr('src');
    const extra = await contentHandler(id);
    promises.push({
      //id: id || null,
      title: title || null,
      poster: poster || null,
      year: extra[0].year || null,
      genres: extra[0].genres || null,
      rating: extra[0].rating || null,
      synopsis: extra[0].synopsis || null,
      authors: extra[0].authors || null,
      director: extra[0].director || null,
      writers: extra[0].writers || null,
      country: extra[0].country || null,
      releaseDate: extra[0].releaseDate || null,
    });
    resolve(promises)
  }));


  return Promise.all(promise.toArray());
};

getALLMovies()
  .then(res =>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res , null , 2))
  })
```

Comment: That's using the Explicit Promise Construction Anti-Pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23803744/3977276  Creating that "new Promise" is not necessary.